# 22.04 thinks my desktop should have wifi, so sets airplane on as I do ot use wifi. This means that bluetooth cannot work. Why?

Tags: networking, bluetooth

As per the title.
Ubuntu 22.04 seems not to understand that my desktop legitimately does not use wifi but has a wired connection. Accordingly, it locks airplane mode on.
This suppresses the operation of bluetooth.
I need bluetooth.

Comment: are you sure your desktop has bluetooth functionality? because often wifi+bluetooth come together, in the same hardware device. What motherboard/device is this? can you post output of `rfkill list all`?

Comment: USB dongle bluetooth, otherwise no on-board bluetooth. USB working fine - mouse, keyboard, etc. Will post output later.

Comment: rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Run `sudo rfkill unblock all`

Answer (score 0):

The airplane mode disables all wireless interfaces e.g. WLAN (Wi-Fi), LTE or other mobile networks, Bluetooth etc.

If you wish to disable Wi-Fi only, you cannot use the airplane mode. Go to **Settings** → **Wi-Fi** and disable Wi-Fi interface.

Comment: This is the problem. I desperately want to turn it off.
However, ubuntu seems to think that not having the facility for WIFI on my desktop - why would I? It is slower than wired. - means that I want airplane mode on and hence want bluetooth, etc to be suppressed. Nothing could be further from the truth!!
Would you want your keyboard to be disabled becauswe you do not have a mouse? This is hoew the realtionship between wifi, bluetooth and airplane mode seems to work.

Comment: Did you check the situation of interfaces in the BIOS?