# permanently set 'wireless mode' so the airplane icon shows it in top bar

Tags: wireless, 22.04, amd-ryzen

whilst there are work arounds
[Permanently Disable Wireless Drivers and Wireless Internet on tablet-PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967388/permanently-disable-wireless-drivers-and-wireless-internet-on-tablet-pc)

, I would like to see the airplane icon in the top bar to prove that wireless is off.
(the best way would be to take out the hardware as I never use wifi )

the setting is in settings, wifi , airplane mode.

but this resets to enabled on reboot. I would like it permanently selected there, so it shows in top bar.

ryzen5
22.04.1
gdm3
5.15.0-56-generic

Comment: the setting is, as it says, also for bluetooth and mobile broadband, which I also want disabled. it would be nice for that setting to have a 'permantly until notified' setting, or 'lock'

Comment: I guess I will have to set a busy script to send keys function + F12 for my ASUS TUF Ryzen laptop here. perhaps query, if possible, if airport mode is on.

Comment: update, silly me, I checked the BIOS and I could disable wireless there, and also bluetooth. top bar now has a ? where the airport icon used to be, and wireless and blutooth are not in the menu top right. hardware is asus tuf ryzen5.  Ubuntu settings, blutooth not found , and no wireless anything under network.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me lovely, and the airport icon shows up the top , I only need to run it on startup/reboot.

not mine, got it from here, so upvote there.

[Turn Airplane Mode on/off via terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348262/turn-airplane-mode-on-off-via-terminal)

```
#!/bin/bash

radio="$(nmcli radio all | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2}')"

if [ "$radio" = "enabled" ]
 then
    nmcli radio all off
else
    nmcli radio all on
fi

if rfkill list bluetooth | grep -q 'yes$' ; then
    rfkill unblock bluetooth
else
    rfkill block bluetooth
fi
```

also I ran it as sh, which is dash not bin (as I understand it). else I could run it as 'bash xxxx,sh'

Comment: this is a great answer.

Comment: thanks, again, not mine. and then again, I have been on the same boot session since 30 Dec. (ASUS TUF vs 3 years of HP Envy lockup Hell both with Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

So less about: how make it turn off / how to make the off status remain as such between refresh or reboot

MORE about: relocating the status icon of the setting to a place more prominent.

As with most cel phones where you can rearrange the notification icons and assign them priorities.

You could research and build a macro that turns off the wifi and then add a line to the REBOOT sequence that initiates that macro near the end of rebooting. If you determine a resource for that please be sure to include.

Does the interface, where your icon currently displays, allow you to interact with the icon as a means of interacting with the settings it represents?

Comment: I *think* you might be able to turn this into an *answer* with some edits.  Rather than *"Can you"*, make it a suggestion as a potential (but unverified) workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
rfkill block all
```

works a treat from [22.04 thinks my desktop should have wifi, so sets airplane on as I do ot use wifi. This means that bluetooth cannot work. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441204/22-04-thinks-my-desktop-should-have-wifi-so-sets-airplane-on-as-i-do-ot-use-wif)  comment in first answer. AND it did not require sudo. simplest solution.

Comment: also see my comment below my OP question, I did it in bios.